# Speeding up firebase storage download

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-storage

I am trying to pull videos from firebase storage and put them into a slideshow on my Android app but the videos take so long to load.  Does anyone have any alternatives or ways to speed up the data download?

Comment: Alternative: upload videos to YouTube and use the YouTube Android Player API. Depending on the connection the video quality will be changed thereby resulting in less buffer times.

Comment: I would but the only problem is then YouTube has the rights

Answer (score 2):

You can store your files in the Regional Storage, such as us-east1.

Please refer to https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/bucket-locations and change your bucket's region to most closest place to you.

Comment: What do you mean by "bucket location"? Whats the "bucket"?

Comment: so bucket location is the location on which server google should store your data. https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/bucket-locations

Comment: e.g. It is recommended that you select asia-northeast1(Tokyo) to provide services to users in Japan.

Comment: Please see https://firebase.googleblog.com/2017/03/multiplying-power-firebase-storage.html for instructions on how to add buckets.

Answer (score 2):

One thing you can do is split your video in smaller chunks when you are uploading
then download chunks one by one as slideshow plays.
It is a good idea because by this way you or your user don't have to wait for whole file.  you can start playing videos as soon as your first chunk is available and then continue downloading next one's in background.
When you chunk video files, you reduce the risk of timeouts. If a small chunk fails to download for whatever reason, you can automatically retry only that chunk, instead of having to restart the entire download.

and yes when firebase is downloading it will do chucking but it'll be random and not much useful to you now because firebase'll do it for download and it'll signal you when file is fully downloaded to play.

Every streaming service does this. even though multithread downloaders also do the same.

you can google to find optimal chunk size and more about it.

I just googled and it looks good.
https://www.limelight.com/blog/multiple-solutions-for-low-latency-live-video-streaming/

Comment: well the thing is that the videos are like 1-10mb so i don't think i should have to split it up, its just taking forever for them to load.  But can i use the link you gave me for non-live streams?

Comment: yeah you can use that for non-live streams also. when it comes to streaming there is not much difference in a way though it's completely different in a way that in live there is a need for push but in non-live you'll use pull method.

Comment: thank you, it's a great link the only problem is that the support employee told me that they require a minimum of 2 tb of bandwidth....and so i don't think i can meet that yet

Comment: oh , I mean was to that article not the service, not the service, i'm not saying you should use that service.

Comment: no i understand, how do you think i would be able to integrate a service like this with firebase?

Comment: I don't know about integrating such service with firebase. i just know how can you build a service like that :)

Comment: That's why I said, I meant to only article, the concept .